# <t:selectOneRadio link to backbean problem

Tags: java, jsf, tomahawk

I have used Tomahawk `<t:selectOneRadio>` in my jsf page. I have reserved one boolean value for each radio button in my back bean, but I have a problem with linking the component to the backing bean. How must I link the component to the backing bean?

Is my data model in backing bean wrong?

This is my code:

```
<t:radio index="0" for="select"></t:radio>
<t:selectOneRadio id="select" layout="spread">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Every" itemValue="Every" />
<h:inputText id="days" /> days 
<br />
<t:radio index="1" for="select"></t:radio>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Every Weekday"
itemValue="Every Weekday" />
</t:selectOneRadio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `value` attribute.

```
<t:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
```

That said, the component is not used the correct way in your code. Only the selectitems should go in the component and the `t:radio` index should start with 0. Here's a rewrite:

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="frequency" value="#{bean.frequency}" layout="spread">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Every" itemValue="Every" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Every weekday" itemValue="Every weekday" />
</t:selectOneRadio>

<t:radio for="frequency" index="0" /><h:inputText value="#{bean.days}" /> days
<br />
<t:radio for="frequency" index="1" />
```

In the bean you need the following:

```
private String frequency;
private Integer days;
// Add/generate getters and setters.
```

Depending on the selection, the selected `itemValue` will be set as `frequency` (which can thus be either `"Every"` or `"Every weekday"`) and the entered `days` will be set as `days`.